# embed builder with awaitMessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    category: 'utility',
    //requirePermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    run: async (message) => {
        message.channel.send("provide title:")
        const response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
            m => m.author.id === message.author.id,
            {
            time: 60000,
            max: 1
            }
        );

            const title = response.first().content;
            let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setColor(0xff9933)
            message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
        }}
```

bot sends provide title: and does nothing else

i tried message collectors a couple of videos but nothing helps. i want bot to ask for title then send embed with this title

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues in your code. The first is you dont await the promise from `<TextChannel>#send` twice. The second issue and root cause of your issue is not placing your filter in the proper location.

change

```js
const response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
            m => m.author.id === message.author.id,
            {
            time: 60000,
            max: 1
            }
        );
```

to

```
const response = await message.channel.awaitMessages({
    time: 60000,
    max: 1,
    filter: (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id
});
```